# Select last values and join with same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 stock containers (AN_S1, AN_S2, AN_S3). I read from a PLC their weight and the state of their motor inverter (QEV1,QEV2,QEV3 [0=OFF, 1=ON]).

valore = weight for Containers (S1,S2,S3); [0-1] for Inverters (QEV1,QEV2,QEV3)
data_ora is a timestamp.

So, every 5 minutes, I read PLC variables. And i have this table:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| nome                              | valore  | data_ora            |
+-----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| AN_S1                             |  3.9725 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
| AN_S2                             |  150.26 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
| AN_S3                             | 207.026 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
|QEV1                               |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
|QEV2                               |       1 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
|QEV3                               |       1 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
|MARCIA_9                           |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
|MARCIA_10                          |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:10:05 |
| AN_S1                             |  0.0005 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
| AN_S2                             |  100.26 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
| AN_S3                             | 977.004 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
|QEV1                               |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
|QEV2                               |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
|QEV3                               |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
| MARCIA_9                          |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
| MARCIA_10                         |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:15:06 |
| AN_S1                             |  367.08 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
| AN_S2                             |   50.26 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
| AN_S3                             |   70135 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
|QEV1                               |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
|QEV2                               |       1 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
|QEV3                               |       1 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
| MARCIA_9                          |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
| MARCIA_10                         |       0 | 2016-09-06 19:20:05 |
+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

I'd like a query to have this. For each container, i want last updated weight and the state of its inverter:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| nome                              | valore  | QEV                 |
+-----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| AN_S1                             |  367.08 | 0                   |
| AN_S2                             |  50.26  | 1                   |
| AN_S3                             | 70135   | 1                   |
+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

Selecting only last (data_ora is a timestamp filed) values (valore) joined with each corrispondending QEV value.

Comment: Does the table have an id column? Your expected output only show where any of the related valore > 0?

Comment: No, I don't have id column. Please read the update.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whee the QEV will come in, but to select the value for the most recen timestamp, use:

```
select T1.nome, T1.valore, T1.data_ora
from Table1 T1
where data_ora = 
    (select max(T2.data_ora) from Table1 T2 where T1.nome = T2.nome)
and T1.nome like 'AN%'
```

And for QEV:

```
select T3.nome, T3.valore as QEV, T3.data_ora
from Table1 T3
where data_ora = 
    (select max(T4.data_ora) from Table1 T4 where T3.nome = T4.nome)
and T3.nome like 'QEV%'
```

Now we join

```
select A1.nome, A1.valore, A2.QEV
from (
    select T1.nome, T1.valore, T1.data_ora
    from Table1 T1
    where data_ora = 
        (select max(T2.data_ora) from Table1 T2 where T1.nome = T2.nome)
    and T1.nome like 'AN%'
) A1
inner join (
    select T3.nome, T3.valore as QEV, T3.data_ora
    from Table1 T3
    where data_ora = 
        (select max(T4.data_ora) from Table1 T4 where T3.nome = T4.nome)
    and T3.nome like 'QEV%'
) A2
    on A1.data_ora = A2.data_ora
```

Comment: Polarix this nearly works you just need to fix the final on statement - for example AND (REPLACE(A1.NAME,'AN_S','') = REPLACE(A2.NAME,'QEV','')) -